# query between two dates using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which is clientbike

```
SELECT stime,etime FROM clientbike

type = datetime
```

Result

```
stime               | etime 
-------------------------------------------- 
2016-04-18 00:00:00 | 2016-05-18 00:00:00
--------------------------------------------
2016-04-05 00:00:00 | 2016-06-05 00:00:00
--------------------------------------------
2016-04-03 00:00:00 | 2016-07-03 00:00:00
```

Now I want to search function:

all query result found 0 but i want 3 ...

Search Query Using >= AND <=

```
   SELECT stime,etime FROM clientbike WHERE 
   stime >= '2016-04-25 00:00:00' AND 
   etime <= '2016-04-26 00:00:00'
```

Wrong

```
   No Result Found...
```

search query using between

```
   SELECT stime,etime FROM clientbike WHERE 
   stime BETWEEN '2016-04-25 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-26 00:00:00' AND 
   etime BETWEEN '2016-04-25 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-26 00:00:00'
```

Wrong

```
   No Result Found...
```

search query using between with str_to_date

```
   SELECT stime,etime FROM clientbike WHERE 
   STR_TO_DATE(stime, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2016-04-25 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-26 00:00:00' AND 
   STR_TO_DATE(etime, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2016-04-25 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-26 00:00:00'
```

Wrong

```
   No Result Found...
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Be very careful about writing dates `d-m-Y`. Depending on where you live it means different things. Write dates `Y-m-d`.

Comment: yes , but date copy for exit data...

Comment: i don't use y-m-d , i use only d-m-Y

Comment: In every day life I use d-m-Y, but in programming I use Y-m-d so there's absolutely no ambiguity. I would highly recommend that you do it too.

Comment: There is no 31 day in June and July 2016.

Comment: It could be an issue if datatype `date` is used.

Comment: No result because you have no Record is between those dates !!! :)

Comment: You etime dates are all over the month 4 !

Comment: i want to between records result .. example  stime -> 6 & etime-> 9  and user search stime ->7 & etime-> 8 then result found stime -> 6 & etime-> 9

Answer (score 2):

```
stime      | etime 
------------------------ 
15-04-2016 | 31-06-2016
```

That format means your fields are `varchar`s and not `date` hence you can not compare them ordinarily like `date`s can be compared.

If you were using proper `date` type field, format would have been `YYYY-MM-DD` and then any standard comparison would work just fine. Since that is not the case you have to convert these strings to dates to compare them correctly.

Best course of action is to change your fields to use correct data type for this purpose, and that is `DATE`

Comment: but , i use only d-m-Y

Comment: if i use date value in mysql my date format auto change and show ' YYYY-MM-DD '...

Comment: You can easily convert the display date to any format that you like

Comment: Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert your columns to be as dates

```
   STR_TO_DATE(stime, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Please try this

```
   SELECT stime,etime FROM clientbike 
   WHERE STR_TO_DATE(stime, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-04-17'
     AND STR_TO_DATE(etime, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-07-26'
```

or

in your database change that column from varchar to date or datetime

**EDIT**

[**sqlfiddle example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12675b/1)

Comment: Yep good! I think OP will go this way cause they dont seem to be eager to make changes to their existing structure

Comment: Try use this updated dates and you will get results . you have no result because the dates are over you searching dates , and no value matches

Comment: Check sqlfiddle example

Comment: i want to between records result .. example stime -> 6 & etime-> 9 and user search stime ->7 & etime-> 8 then result found stime -> 6 & etime-> 9

Answer (score 0):

First thing I can see in your question your stime and etime column is string type so change data type to date in database and for debugging you can check below query.

You need to just copy below query and execute in mysql, then you can see this query is returning number of count entry from staring date to end date.

You can achieve this in two way,

**Option 1**

```
    SET @FromDate := '2016-04-1'  
    SET @ToDate := '2016-04-30' 

    SELECT COUNT(* ) FROM clientbike
    WHERE stime >= @FromDate AND etime <= @ToDate
```

This is covering all date range scenario like selected `@FromDate` and `@ToDate` both are within start and end column in table.

**Option 2**

```
     SET @FromDate := '2016-04-1'  
     SET @ToDate := '2016-04-30' 
     SELECT count(*) FROM clientbike WHERE stime BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND etime BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
```